# The intersection complex and the Cohen-Macaulay property

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, perverse-sheaves, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $\Delta:Y\rightarrow X$ a closed immersion of $k$-schemes of finite type and equidimensionnal.

We assume that $\Delta^{*}[-d]IC_{X}=IC_{Y}$, if $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay, does it imply that $Y$ is Cohen-Macaulay?

Comment: Let assume also that both X and Y are equidimensionnal, and that a resolution of singularities for X gives by base change a resolution of singularities for Y.

Comment: Could you explain what it means by $IC_{-}$? Are they canonical bundle of $Y$ and $X$ respectively? Also what is $d$?

Comment: d is the codimension, IC is the intersection complex.
